# how to make bar chart from blank to colored?

Tags: matlab

by following matlab code I would like to make the coloured bar-chart but I am getting blank figure as [bar-chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saXqM.jpg), please let me know how do I resolve it?

```
col(1,:) = [0 200 0]/255; 
col(2,:) = [0 0 200]/255; 
col(3,:) = [200 0 0]/255; 
x_axis = categorical({'01', '02', '03'});
y_axis = [68.52 80.69 79.38];
figure
b = bar(x_axis, y_axis,'FaceColor','flat');
b.CData = col;
title('Comparison of average accuracy among existing and proposed approach')
xlabel('Serial Number of existing approach and proposed feature')
ylabel('Accuracy')
```

Comment: Works for me. I'd try closing any active figures using `close all` in the command window and maybe remove the unnecessary `figure` line.

Comment: @sanjay gupta which version do you use? On my Laptop with R2017a, CData is not a property of the bar-chart. Therefore, it doesn't work there. I think, everything newer than R2018a should work.

Comment: actually, I was making the multiple figures with the different number of bars using same variable 'col' so there was the problem, I need to change the name of the 'col' variable for each figure if figures have the different number of bars. this way problem is resolved, thank you

Comment: @Till version is 2017b and problem is solved using different name of variable col for each figure, thanks for you try